# Is there a way to check if value is date and returning in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a attribute `beginDate` in all nodes labeled as `laws`  , but I would like to query and return all nodes that the value isn`t a date - to check if the system has made a mistake in any situation - .

Therefore the pattern is a date, the attribute `beginDate` is safe as a string `YYYY-mm-dd`.
I`m thinking something like. :

match (l:laws) where l.apoc.date.isdate(l.beginDate) return l.name, l.beginDate

I`m using Neo4j 4.2.4
1,5 k of nodes.

Comment: so the beginDate is a string of date structure?

Comment: Yeah . But I`m afraid that in some rows that date structure comming broked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this APOC function:  apoc.meta.cypher.isType

Ref:  https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/overview/apoc.meta/apoc.meta.cypher.isType/

For example:

```
RETURN apoc.meta.cypher.isType(date(), "DATE") AS output; will return  True
```

Thus:

```
match (l:laws) where apoc.meta.cypher.isType(l.beginDate, "DATE") return l.name, l.beginDate
```

Will give you records with beginDate is date format.

if beginDate is datetime, then use DATE_TIME in the 2nd parameter.

Update: if you want to get records where beginDate is not date then

```
match (l:laws) where NOT apoc.meta.cypher.isType(l.beginDate, "DATE") return l.name, l.beginDate
```

Comment: It's close, you helped me a lot, but still not . Due to a error my attribute is string (not a date) , as  a sample : '2000-12-04' . I discovered a wrong string like '2010*-12-05' in the records.  When test your solution return me a error, when try to convert '2010*-12-05'. match (l:laws) where apoc.meta.cypher.isType(date(l.beginDate), "DATE") return l.name, l.beginDate

Comment: You dont convert beginDate to date. You check if the value is date format. My answer will give you data where beginDate is date format.

Comment: To get records where beginDate is string,  copy my answer and change 2nd param DATE to STRING

Comment: An analogy is this. There are different LAWS like tax laws, criminal laws, family laws. So you dont change tax law into another law because their nature (or format) are different. Right?

Comment: I updated my answer to give you rows where beginDate is NOT date format.